How to use perltidy to reformat code in Visual Studio Code
Windows, Visual Studio Code. I have installed the extension: "Perl Navigator" and perl is installed in my computer system, perltidy is installed. The code in a file is like this:
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use          warnings ;
use Params::Validate;

my $x     =4;
my    $y = "AB";

What can I do to reformat this code with perltidy with Visual Studio Code?
In vim I do this:
ESC :1,$!perltidy

I installed several extensions for Visual Studio Code but none of these tell me how to use them.

Maybe solved... VSCode has a beautifier way for every kind of file. A VSCode extension must get installed to use it.
I installed the extension: Simple Perl. After that I highlighted some perl code in some perl file. Right-click - Menue: Format selection. The code gets formatted.

Feel free to post an answer to your own question instead of leaving a comment.

Also, send feedback to Perl Navigator if you have an answer that you didn't find in the docs. I don't use it myself, but it's gaining traction I think. :)

VSCode has a beautifier way for every kind of file.
A VSCode extension must get installed to use it. I installed the extension: Simple Perl. After that I highlighted some perl code in some perl file. Right-click - Menue: Format selection. The code gets formatted.
